# Laravel extract value from array if not key exist

Tags: arrays, laravel-6

how extract string from array value?

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "dmapi-auth=d0e38a35d83fea420d0bb1e93e2f4b964d0a205b; path=/"
]
```

so value is "dmapi-auth=d0e38a35d83fea420d0bb1e93e2f4b964d0a205b;"

I need to get string after dmapi-auth= and before ; -char.
like **d0e38a35d83fea420d0bb1e93e2f4b964d0a205b**

Thanks Mika.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
$arr = [
    0 => "dmapi-auth=d0e38a35d83fea420d0bb1e93e2f4b964d0a205b; path=/"
];
$arr = explode(';', $arr[0]);

$arr = substr($arr[0], strpos($arr[0], "=") + 1);
```

Comment: thank you,

I have even extended little bit:

  $authSid =  $res->getHeader('Set-Cookie');
     $arr = explode(';', $authSid[0]);

       $arr = substr($arr[0], strpos($arr[0], "=") + 1);

        dump ($arr);

works as I need.